# Matrix Column scaling

Tags: matrices

I wonder is there any way to scale the column of the matrix by multiplying the matrix on the left? In the other words, let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2 \\ 3&4 \end{bmatrix}$ and $D = \begin{bmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. $AD = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 \\ 6 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$. Is there exist a $D'$ where $D'A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 6 \\ 6 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Are your $A$ matrices always square and invertible?

Comment: Yes. It is square and invertible.

Comment: If $AD=D'A$ then $D'=ADA^{-1}$.

Comment: I never thought of that! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, as long as $A$ is square and invertible it's quite simple to find:

$$D'A = A_s$$

therefore

$$D' = A_s A^{-1}$$